# Is it possible to have only the features of an Orchard CMS module display in the Enable Features page of the Admin section?

Tags: orchardcms

Let me clear this up a bit, because the question itself may appear to be a bit confusing:

I have a module- lets call this module `AB module`. This module has 2 features- lets call them `feature A` and `feature B`.

Here is an example module manifest file:

```
Name: AB Module
AntiForgery: enabled
Version: 1.0
OrchardVersion: 1.0
Description: Test module with 2 features
Category: My New Category
Features:
    AbModule.FeatureA:
        Name: Feature A
        Category: My New Category
    AbModule.FeatureB:
        Name: Feature B
        Category: My New Category
```

Currently, the `My New Category` section of the `Modules` page contains three items- `AB Module`, `Feature A` and `Feature B`.

Because my module contains no functionality outside of `Feature A` and `Feature B`, I would like to hide the option to enable `AB Module` from the user as it provides no functionality without the child features being enabled, and could cause confusion.

Is this possible? And if so- how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default one will always be there by design. Code that's not explicitly described with optional `OrchardFeature` attribute will fall into this feature.

You need to treat the default feature (the one with the same identifier as the module) as `FeatureA` and the other one as `FeatureB`. Assuming your module project is named `AbModule` it should look like this:

```
Name: AB Module
AntiForgery: enabled
Version: 1.0
OrchardVersion: 1.0
Description: Test module with 2 features
Category: My New Category
Features:
    AbModule:
        Name: Feature A
        Category: My New Category
    AbModule.FeatureB:
        Name: Feature B
        Category: My New Category
```

In this case `AB Module` won't be shown as a feature anymore - you'll see `Feature A` and `Feature B` only.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have been doing in other modules, but I just wondered if what I asked was at all possible. Looks like I'll keep on doing it this way.

Comment: I have a  similar question. How can I tell that when ever I enable feature A feature AB also get activated automatically? Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you meant 'feature B'. All you need to do is add a line under 'AbModule' section : 
'Dependencies: AbModule.FeatureB'
Take a look at this doc: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/manifest-files